# Outlook for exchange accounts

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm trying to distinguish between following two versions of outlook on the Mac and the objective is to have exchange email on my system.

I installed the (2) myself from an office 365 account. The second version came pre-installed on a client machine, I double checked both have same versions (Latest 16.43).

**Question**: Why Exchange account setting is available in one copy and not the other.

1. Exchange is available

[image: match found]

2. Exchange is not available (Coming soon)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Have you enabled the New Outlook switch?

If you enabled the New Outlook switch, you would indeed get the situation as "2. Exchange is not available (Coming soon)". Microsoft has released [the The new Outlook for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439), but the features it could support are limited.（Have not supported Exchange email accounts yet.）

If this is your case, you could just disable this switch and you issue could be resolved.

Comment: ah... this might be the case, any idea on when are they going to ship the feature, any published roadmap please?

Comment: Have not found any roadmap about that yet, maybe you could check the Release notes for reference. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-for-mac-release-notes-for-beta-channel-builds-d6347358-5613-433e-a49e-a9a0e8e0462a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: I was able to stay in New Outlook by adding the Exchange account as IMAP (obviously without calendar and contacts), though this required selecting StartTLS for the outgoing mail server connection, and enabling SMTP at the Exchange host. New Outlook should be called "unfinished Outlook".